# C++ 'object'? alike the .NET's and Java's object

Tags: c++

In C# you can write the below and if the type is correct it just works. Is there something like that which exist in C++?

```
object o = anything;
...
var anything2=(Anything)o;
```

Comment: boost::any, boost::variant or generics

Comment: There's nothing exactly like that in C++. What is it exactly that you are trying to do, maybe there's some other solution to your problem.

Comment: Well @Paul, i'd like to be able to do at least what is in my example. Maybe the cast can be a template get function

Comment: @acidzombie24, but what is the reason you want to do that? Explain to us *why* do you want to do that and we may suggest a better solution than what you're trying to do.

Comment: @svick mostly to see how its implemented. Especially parts regarding the type system

Comment: @svick the only reason i'd use it would be if i tried to parse a file and inserted random objects into a tree like a json parser. But i don't plan on doing that. I wouldn't want to use enums for that.

Comment: "to see how its implemented" - it's not implemented at all, in C++. For a json parser, the set of types parsed is fixed. You can create a `boost::variant<AllParsedTypes...>` to hold any one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe boost::any is what you are looking for? It is not quite the same but might be applicable for your particular scenario

Comment: I think that does exactly what i want.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using object use interface or templates instead. Which is the reason you need something like that?? In case if you need to store a group of objects in the same list (for example) or something like that then all of your objects probably has something common. So all of them should implement an interface and your list will be like ( std::list< IMyObject* > ).

Comment: I probably should have said this but i mostly want to look at how it would be implemented safely. So i am looking at boost::any. But +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want a type that is a pointer to anything, then that would be `void*`.

The difference is that in C#, you can safely convert (almost) anything into a reference. In C++, it's not that simple and if you have something that's not a pointer, you can't just convert it to `void*` and expect it to work.

But, I try to avoid using `object` in C# whenever possible. And the same applies to `void*` in C++. Try to use the type system, not work around it.